# Automatically extract data conditionally from another worksheet .Are there any options for me to automate this process using Excel Macro or Formulas?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, automation

I have an obstacle to automatically retrieve the data that are unique from the New Info that are the not available inside the Masterlist and add into the Masterlist on a routine basis.

Are there any ways to setup formulas or macros to identify the list in the Masterlist that are not available in the New Info worksheet?

[image: Master List]

[image: New Info]

[image: Ideal Result]
**Above would be the Ideal Result**

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to copy all over and then use the delete duplicates feature of Excel. • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: My bad. It wasnt my intention to get people to build the code. I was hoping for an explanation that would say that this would require VBA's or perhaps just a simple formula. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Feeling generous so i'll try help and hope you can follow along. if you need to know how to add module to VBA, i've added this at the bottom.

I have functions i've created which do various things so that you only need to write a few lines of code to accomplish the task. top section is the code and the bottom section are the functions which allow this task to be so easy!

the idea is:

1. You 'Extract' the data
2. You 'Transform' the data
3. You 'Load' the Data back to the spreadsheet

### The code would look something like this:

```
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/syed-n-928b2490/
Option Base 1

Sub WorkWithData()

Dim dataArray1() As Variant ' empty array for data
Dim dataArray2() As Variant ' empty array for data
Dim combinedArray() As Variant ' empty array for data

'First Get the data from both sheets and combine the data sets together - note the columns must be same
dataArray1() = GetArr("MasterList")
dataArray2() = GetArr("New Info")
'dataArray2() = GetArr("New Info",,,,,"C:/users/documents/bob.xlsx") ' if you want to obtain data directly from an external workbook you can use this line instead

'join the two datas together and remove dupes
combinedArray() = UnionArr(dataArray1(), dataArray2(), , True)

'Specify the sheet you want to paste the data in
PasteArr "MasterList", combinedArray()

Erase combinedArray
Erase dataArray1
Erase dataArray2

End Sub







''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'  General Functions
'  created by:          Syed Noshahi
'  linked in:           https://www.linkedin.com/in/syed-n-928b2490/
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



'------- ---------------------- ---------
'------- Get Data into an Array ---------
'------- ---------------------- ---------

Function GetArr(SheetName As String, Optional ColumnForSize As Long = 1, Optional RowForSize As Long = 1, Optional Rowstart As Long = 1, Optional ColStart As Long = 1, Optional sExternalWBFullName As String = "", Optional bLeaveFileOpen As Boolean = False, Optional lSpecifyRows As Long = 0, Optional lSpecifyCols As Long = 0) As Variant()

Dim vArray() As Variant

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

On Error GoTo ErrH
    If Len(sExternalWBFullName) > 0 Then
        i = Len(sExternalWBFullName)
        Do
            i = i - 1
            s = Mid(sExternalWBFullName, i, 1)
        Loop Until s = "\" Or (i = 1)
        If i <> 0 Then
            sWBName = Right(sExternalWBFullName, Len(sExternalWBFullName) - i)
            sWBPath = Replace(sExternalWBFullName, sWBName, "", , , 1)
            For Each wbs In Application.Workbooks
                If wbs.Name = sWBName Then
                    sWBPath = ""
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
    If Len(sWBPath) > 0 And Len(sWBName) > 0 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sExternalWBFullName, False, True)
    ElseIf Len(sWBName) > 0 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks(sWBName)
    End If: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SheetName):    On Error GoTo 0

With ws
    If .FilterMode = True Then .ShowAllData
    If lSpecifyRows > 0 Then
        lRow = lSpecifyRows
    Else
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColumnForSize).End(xlUp).Row - Rowstart + 1
    End If
    If lSpecifyCols > 0 Then
        lCol = lSpecifyCols
    Else
        lCol = .Cells(RowForSize, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End If
    If lRow > 1 Or lCol > 1 Then
        vArray() = .Cells(Rowstart, ColStart).Resize(lRow, lCol).Value2
        GetArr = vArray()
    End If
End With

If Len(sWBName) > 0 And Not bLeaveFileOpen Then
    wb.Close False
End If


EndFunction:
Exit Function

ErrH:
Debug.Print "Worksheet name '" & SheetName & "' not found."
Resume EndFunction

End Function



'------- -------------------- ---------
'------- Paste Array to Sheet ---------
'------- -------------------- ---------

Function PasteArr(SheetName As String, vArray() As Variant, Optional ColumnForSize As Long = 1, Optional bClearContents As Boolean = True, Optional bLastRow As Boolean, Optional bOmitFirstRow As Boolean, Optional sWBName As String = "", Optional lPasteCol As Long = 1, Optional lStartRow As Long = 1)

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

On Error GoTo ErrH
    If Len(sWBName) > 0 Then Set wb = Workbooks(sWBName)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName): On Error GoTo 0

x = 0

With ws
    If .FilterMode = True Then .ShowAllData
    If bClearContents Then
        If lPasteCol > 1 And ColumnForSize = 1 Then ColumnForSize = lPasteCol
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColumnForSize).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow > 1 And Len(.Cells(lStartRow, lPasteCol)) > 0 Then .Cells(lStartRow, lPasteCol).Resize(lRow - lStartRow + 1, UBound(vArray, 2)).ClearContents
    End If
    If bOmitFirstRow Then
        For i = LBound(vArray, 2) To UBound(vArray, 2)
            vArray(LBound(vArray), i) = vArray(UBound(vArray), i)
            vArray(UBound(vArray), i) = ""
        Next
        x = 1
    End If
    If Not (Not vArray()) Then
        If bLastRow Then
            If lPasteCol > 1 And ColumnForSize = 1 Then ColumnForSize = lPasteCol
            lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColumnForSize).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(lRow, lPasteCol).Resize(UBound(vArray) - x, UBound(vArray, 2)) = vArray()
        Else
            .Cells(lStartRow, lPasteCol).Resize(UBound(vArray) - x, UBound(vArray, 2)) = vArray()
        End If
    End If
End With


EndFunction:
Exit Function

ErrH:
Debug.Print "Worksheet name '" & SheetName & "' not found."
Resume EndFunction

End Function


'------- -------------- ------
'------- Union an Array ------
'------- -------------- ------

Function UnionArr(arrTemp1(), arrTemp2(), Optional RemoveColumns As Boolean = True, Optional RemoveDuplicates As Boolean = False)

' Function requires two arrays of same column size. First array dictates the size

Dim k As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim vTempArr()
Dim vArray(): Dim vHoldingArray(1 To 1)
Dim Od1 As Object: Set Od1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Od1.CompareMode = 1

If RemoveColumns Then
    k = 1
    m = 2
Else
    k = 0
    m = 1
End If
r = UBound(arrTemp1) + UBound(arrTemp2) - k

ReDim vArray(r, UBound(arrTemp1, 2))

For i = 1 To UBound(arrTemp1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrTemp1, 2)
        vArray(i, j) = arrTemp1(i, j)
    Next
Next

i = i - 1
For l = m To UBound(arrTemp2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrTemp2, 2)
        vArray(i + l - k, j) = arrTemp2(l, j)
    Next
Next


'if removing duplicates has been selected we remove where the entire Row is a dupe
If RemoveDuplicates Then
    k = 1
    ' first get all the columns together and store in a dictionary
    For i = 2 To UBound(vArray)
        vHoldingArray(1) = ""
        For j = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
            vHoldingArray(1) = vHoldingArray(1) & vArray(i, j)
        Next
        If Not Od1.Exists(vHoldingArray(1) & "key") Then
            k = k + 1
            Od1(vHoldingArray(1) & "key") = 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim vTempArr(k, UBound(vArray, 2))
    k = 1
    Od1.RemoveAll
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
        vTempArr(k, i) = vArray(k, i)
    Next
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(vArray)
        vHoldingArray(1) = ""
        For j = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
            vHoldingArray(1) = vHoldingArray(1) & vArray(i, j)
        Next
        If Not Od1.Exists(vHoldingArray(1) & "key") Then
            Od1(vHoldingArray(1) & "key") = 1
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
                vTempArr(k, j) = vArray(i, j)
            Next
        End If
    Next

    vArray() = vTempArr()
End If

UnionArr = vArray()

Erase vTempArr()
Erase vArray()
Set Od1 = Nothing

End Function
```

---

1. on Excel press Alt + F11 (opens VBA editor)
2. view --> Project explorer
3. on the top left hand side click your file name (in the project window)
4. insert --> module

---

Comment: I appreciate this! Thank you. I hope this would help people that would encounter a similar challenges out there.